# Vectorised form of `in` in Julia

Tags: julia

I am attempting to find the indices of a vector, where the elements are contained in another vector. For instance, let `a = [2, 4, 6, 8]`, `b = [2, 6]`, the desired output would be the vector `[1, 3]`.  I have tried `find(a .in b)`, however `a .in b` is a syntax error.  The vectorised form `in.(a, b)` raises a `DimensionMismatch` error because the vectors cannot be broadcast to a common shape, and while `in.(a, b')` allows broadcasting, the result:

```
true   false
false  false
false  true
false  false
```

is less than ideal.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

As [Alex Riley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3923281/alex-riley) pointed out, the referenced question/answer can be used to solve this

```
julia> a = [2, 4, 6, 8]
    4-element Array{Int64,1}:
     2
     4
     6
     8

julia> b = [2, 6]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 6

julia> find(in.(a, (b, )))
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `indexin`.

```
a = [2, 4, 6, 8]
b = [2, 6]
indexin(b,a) # returns [1,3]
```

Comment: Sorry, just realized that was the answer in @'Alex Riley' answer above